# python OOP : extended class

Tags: python

ver:python3.6.1

source code:

```
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self,name):
    '''Return all contacts that contain the search value in their name.'''
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
            return matching_contacts

class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()
    def __init__(self,name,email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
```

then run it in IDLE

```
c1 = Contact("John A","johna@example.com")
c2 = Contact("John B","johnb@example.com")
c3 = Contact("Jenna C","jennac@example.com")
[c.name for c in Contact.all_contacts.search('John')]
```

the result should be `['John A','John B']`, but my idle show me`['John A']`

I want figure out whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Why would a contact know about the contact list in the first place?

Comment: don't extend from built-in, use the ABC module.

Comment: The indentation of `return matching_contacts` is wrong; it needs to be *outside the loop*.

Comment: And you are wildly mixing instance and class members...

Comment: found = [item for item in all_contacts if "John" in item]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's because your "return" is in wrong position.

```
class ContactList(list):
def search(self,name):
'''Return all contacts that contain the search value in their name.'''
    matching_contacts = []
    for contact in self:
        if name in contact.name:
            matching_contacts.append(contact)
    return matching_contacts
```